# How to achieve an "OJ looking" Pale Ale (a la Trillium/Tired Hands)

Tags: all-grain, recipe, pale

Brewing a Juicy, All Grain Pale Ale and looking to get the look of a Trillium/Tired hands "orange Juice looking" ale, meaning the hazy, turbid, slightly murky look (see pic below)

The base will be Pilsner/MO.  Then I have CaraPils in the mash for some head retention, but what can I do for the look?  Also, have CaraRed in as well.

[image]

Comment: This post makes me thirsty.

Comment: the picture alone...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prevailing wisdom on these so called "east coast" IPAs is three fold:  The use of ~10% of flaked oats in the grist. A combo of super huge late kettle additions as well as dry hopping.  Lastly, the use of London Ale III from Wyeast (Wyeast 1318).  Despite London Ale III being a great flocculating English Ale yeast, in the presence of huge amounts of hop oils, it just fails to flocculate out.

I have brewed a couple DIPAs attempting to emulate the style and the London Ale III seems to do the trick for sure. This is also being reported by a couple brewing buddies of mine doing the same thing.

Pilsner and MO will be nice.  I used Pils and Golden promise 50/50.  The rest of the grist was 12% Oats and a touch of caramunich for color (6oz).

I used 4oz of hops in the last 10 minutes of the boil and dry hopped with 6 oz of hops total at the end of primary.  Got a gravy like cloudiness.  With the right specialty grains you can get the brilliant orange color you pictures.  It doesn't take much coloring effort to get it to stand out because the haze makes it pretty dominant.

Comment: You might consider carared at around 5% of total fermentable to get the orange colour.

Comment: @TobiasPatton Yes!  Lots of good options here.  The caramunich is what I had on hand when I brewed.  Carared is not a malt I have played with yet so this might be a good opportunity.

Comment: awesome.  I have a very little hop addition at 60 - the rest is at all late addition.  Also, London III was what I have from previous research.  Thanks for the great notes

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it with just that grain bill.

For that look and mouth feel you need to use oats or a lot of wheat.

- Use a high mash temp for bigger protiens.
- Short boil to keep the proteins, avoid the hot break, basically a slow simmer just for hops and sanitation
- Slow chill to allow more chill haze, avoid the cold break.

Doing this will make a DMS bomb with pils grain, I would replace it with a lower sulfer grain or use Pils DME but will have less hot break material. Kind of a catch 22.

Hope this helps.

Keep in mind many of those juicy IPAs actually use fruit to get thier profile.

Answer (score 0):

People spend too much time worrying about the grain bill.  I have made NE style IPA using zero wheat or oats.  Carapils by nature adds mouthfeel, My last one was 88 percent Maris Otter, 8 percent Vienna, and 4 percent Carapils.  It was super hazy.  The haze comes from the reaction of hops and yeast.  If you use S-04, Nottingham, 1318, or some Conan strain of yeast, and hop it continually during active fermentation, it's going to be hazy.